# Div will not automatically close when click inside item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/scrfbe95/

Right now im using a main div with a list of item with a link once you click a certein list item it will show another div on the right side of the main div.

But what im trying to do is when u click a certein link inside the main div the main div will not close.

```
<div id="main-div1" class="main-div">
  Main div 1
  <div class="content">
        <ul>
          <li> <a href=""> item 1 </a> </li>
           <li> <a href=""> item 1 </a> </li>

       </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="main-div2" class="main-div">
  Main div 2
  <div class="content">
        <ul>
          <li> <a href=""> item 1 </a> </li>
           <li> <a href=""> item 1 </a> </li>

       </ul>  </div>
</div>
<div id="main-div3" class="main-div">
  Main div 3
  <div class="content">
        <ul>
          <li> <a href=""> item 1 </a> </li>
           <li> <a href=""> item 1 </a> </li>

       </ul>  </div>
</div>


.main-div {
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

.main-div > .content {
  display: none;
  color: #fff;
}


(function($) {
    $(document).on('click','.main-div',function() { showMainDiv($(this)); });

  function showMainDiv($el) {
    var $elContent = $el.find('.content');
        if ($elContent.is(':visible')) {
        $elContent.stop(true,true).slideUp(500);
    }
    else {
      $('.main-div').find('.content').stop(true,true).not($elContent).slideUp(500);
      $elContent.slideDown(500);
    }
  }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: can you add simple example or create fiddle

Comment: Hi @Omi i already figured it out whats going on. what im trying to do if u click a certein list item the main div will not close. but right now the main div closes this is the fiddle if u click a certein item inside it will automatically close https://jsfiddle.net/scrfbe95/

Comment: You dont want to hide menu if you click on content right?

Comment: @omi Yes:) it will only hide when you click another main menu or main div

Answer (score 0):

Modify the click listener to only react if the div clicked is the intended div like this

```
$(document).on('click','.main-div',function(e) {
  if (e.target !== this)
    return;

  showMainDiv($(this)); });
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/scrfbe95/1/);